# Is the projection of a zero mean/identity covariance distribution on the unit sphere surface uniform?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $ \mathcal D $ be a continuous distribution on $ \mathbb R^d $ with **zero mean** and **identity covariance matrix** and let $ \mathbf X = (X_1, \dots, X_d) \sim \mathcal D$.

> Is it true that $ \mathbf X / \lVert \mathbf X \rVert_2 $ is uniformly distributed over the surface of the unit sphere $S^{d-1} \triangleq \{\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^d : \lVert \mathbf x \rVert_2 = 1\}$?

I've seen that this holds in the case of the multivariate standard normal distribution, but does it generally hold for the family of zero mean and identity covariance distributions as defined above?

Comment: This is true, for example, if $\mathbf X$ is spherically symmetric about $\mathbf 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $X_i$ to be $+1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and $-1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, where the $X_i$ are independent and identically distributed. Each of the $X_i$ has mean $0$ and variance $1$. Since they are independent, their covariance equals $0$. Hence the vector $\textbf{X}=(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ has mean $0$ and covariance matrix $\mathbb I$.

However, note that the vector $\textbf{X}$ can only take finitely many values. Hence, the projection $\frac{\textbf{X}}{\Vert\textbf{X}\Vert}$ cannot be uniformly distributed on $\mathbb S^{n-1}$.

A similar argument holds if the $X_i$ follow any discrete distribution.

**EDIT:**
Let me now answer your modified question: The idea is simple: Construct a probability measure $\Lambda$ on $\mathbb S^{d-1}$ and a probability measure $R$ on $(0,\infty)$ with $\Lambda$ being symmetric enough so that if $Y\sim \Lambda$ and $Z\sim R$, then $Y\cdot Z$ has mean $0$ and covariance $\mathbb I$.

We construct $\Lambda$ (here only on $\mathbb S^2$) in the following way: Split $\mathbb S^2$ into $8$ segments: Around each "pole", i.e. around $(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)$ pick a segment that is symmetric around that pole. Let $\Lambda$ have mass $1/6$ on each of the segments and let $\Lambda$ be conditionally uniformly distributed on each segment.

For the remaining $4$ segments, i.e. the segments symmetric around the vectors $\big(\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 2},\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\big)$, let $\Lambda$ have mass $\frac{1}{12}$, again being conditionally uniformly distributed on each segment.

Now, if $X=(X_1,X_2)=Y\cdot Z$, with $Y\sim \Lambda$ and $Z$ some variable supported on $(0,\infty)$, we have the symmetry $$(X_1,X_2)\stackrel{d}{=}\big( \pm X_1,\pm X_2\big)$$ for any choice of $\pm$. As a consequene, both $\mathbb EX_1=\mathbb EX_2=0$ and $$\text{Cov}(X_1,X_2)=\text{Cov}(-X_1,X_2)=-\text{Cov}(X_1,X_2)$$ from which it follows that $\text{Cov}(X_1,X_2)=0$.

Now simply choose $Z$ so that we achieve variance $1$ and the vector $X$ satisfies your assumptions, however $$\frac{X}{\Vert X\Vert}\sim\Lambda \neq \text{Uniform}(\mathbb S^{1})$$

Comment: Thank you, but I was actually referring to the continuous case where the distribution is supported on $\mathbb R^d$ (perhaps I should clarify that). Can your argument be generalized in the continuous case?

Comment: @entechnic I have modified my answer to include a counterexample for the continuous case.